# How can I make this same graph ant g2 plot

Tags: reactjs, charts, antv, g2plot

I'm trying to implement this same graph, I almost have it but I can't put the titles that are in gray, for each category to each subgroup, do you know how to do it?

[image]

that's how I have it so far
[image]

I am using react and ant g2 plot, I leave you the link of the official page https://antv-g2plot-v1.gitee.io/zh/examples/treemap/rect/API